# Siebel > Empty Column name is being selected when clicked on Button with CopyRecord method

Tags: siebel

I am trying to copy a record in Siebel and I used venilla method CopyRecord. I placed a button on the applet and called CopyRecord method behind it. On clicking the method I am getting this error on UI:

```
SBL-DBC-00105: An error has occurred executing a Sql statement.

Please continue or ask your systems administrator to check your application configuration if the problem persists.
```

I checked in logs and here is the details:

```
DBCLog  DBCLogError 1   000000025a2722fc:0  2017-12-06 03:31:01 OCIStmtExecute: SELECT
      T19.CONFLICT_ID,
      T19.LAST_UPD,
      T19.CREATED,
      T19.LAST_UPD_BY,
      T19.CREATED_BY,
      T19.MODIFICATION_NUM,
      T19.ROW_ID,
      T19.ROW_ID,
      T19.LAST_UPD,
      T19.,
      T19.APPEALED_FLG,
      T19.PS_APPL_ID,
      T19.APPR_TEMP_ID,
      T19.EVAL_ASSESS_ID,
      T19.ASGN_USR_EXCLD_FLG,
      T19.AUDIT_EMP_ID,
      T19.X_AUDIT_SERIAL_NUM,
      T16.X_CPC,
      T19.CASE_NUM,
      T16.ATTRIB_44,
      T19.SERIAL_NUM,
      T16.ATTRIB_01,
      T19.CATEGORY_TYPE_CD,
      T19.CITY,
      T19.CLASS_CD,
      T19.CLOSED_DT,
      T16.ATTRIB_42,
      T16.ATTRIB_47,
      T16.ATTRIB_45,
      T19.COUNTRY,
      T16.ATTRIB_44,
      T19.CASE_DT,
      T16.ATTRIB_07,
      T19.DESC_TEXT,
      T19.X_REFER_TO_PROSECUTION_FLG,
      T19.X_ASSIGN_AUTO_MANUAL,
      T16.ATTRIB_04,
      T19.X_REHAB_COURT_PROCEEDING_FLAG,
      T16.ATTRIB_09,
      T19.X_APPLICANT_ID,
      T19.X_CASE_CHARGES,
      T19.X_COURT_SESSION_DT,
      T19.X_COURT_SESSION_DT,
      T7.OCCUR_DT,
      T19.X_CRNT_SESSN_ID,
      T19.X_DIVISION_NAME,
      T10.POSTN_ID,
      T19.X_JOINCASE_FLG,
      T19.X_JOINCASE_ID,
      T16.ATTRIB_26,
      T19.,
      T19.X_OLD_SERIAL_NUM,
      T19.X_ON_BEHALF_ID,
      T19.X_PANEL_ID,
      T13.NAME,
      T19.X_PANEL_SCHED_ID,
      T8.POSTN_ID,
      T19.X_OFFENSE_ID,
      T16.X_POLICE_DIVISION,
      T19.X_POLICE_OTHERS,
      T4.POSTN_TYPE_CD,
      T16.X_REHAB_ARCHIVE_REASON,
      T16.X_REHAB_DESCRIPTION,
      T16.X_DATE_1,
      T19.X_ROOT_ROW_ID,
      T19.X_SR_ID,
      T16.X_REHAB_NOTES,
      T15.OCCUR_DT,
      T19.X_CLOB_02,
      T19.ORG_GROUP_ID,
      T19.CHANGED_FLG,
      T19.X_CASE_NAME,
      T16.X_COURTHOUSE,
      T16.X_DISPOSITION,
      T16.X_DISTRICT_NUM,
      T16.X_INTERPRETER,
      T16.X_JUDGE,
      T16.X_JURISDICTION,
      T16.X_PROSECUTOR,
      T16.X_STATUES,
      T19.X_FILING_APPEAL_DATE,
      T19.TYPE_CD,
      T19.X_BUNDLE_ID,
      T19.X_CM_TYPE,
      T19.X_CASE_DATE,
      T19.X_PARTY_TYPE,
      T16.CATEGORY_CODE,
      T19.X_COMPLEXITY,
      T19.X_CONVICTED,
      T19.X_CONVICTED_ID,
      T19.X_COPY_APPLY_DATE,
      T19.X_COPY_ISSUANCE_DATE,
      T19.X_COPY_JUDGMENT_DT,
      T19.X_COURT_FEE_VALUE,
      T19.X_DAYS_APPLICABLE,
      T16.ATTRIB_24,
      T19.LOCAL_SEQ_NUM,
      T19.X_DIARY_DATE,
      T19.X_DIARY_NUM,
      T16.X_DISABLED_FLAG,
      T19.X_DISTRICT,
      T19.X_JUDGE_ID,
      T19.X_FIR_NUM,
      T19.X_FIR_REGISTRATION_DT,
      T16.X_FAST_TRACK,
      T19.X_FEE_APPLICABLE,
      T19.X_FEE_TO_PAY,
      T16.X_FEMALE_FLAG,
      T16.X_GOVT_OFFICIAL,
      T19.X_IS_APPEAL,
      T19.X_IS_REVISION,
      T19.X_JUDGE_DESIGNATION,
      T19.X_JUDGE_NAME_URDU,
      T19.X_JUDGEMENT_DT,
      T16.X_JUVENILE_FLAG,
      T19.X_LEGAL_TIME_ELASPED,
      T19.X_COUNTY,
      T19.X_OTHER_CATEGORY,
      T16.X_OVERSEAS,
      T14.SERIAL_NUM,
      T14.X_SRL_NUMBER,
      T14.X_CASE_NAME,
      T14.X_SRL_NUMBER,
      T14.STATUS_CD,
      T19.X_QUEUE_NUMBER,
      T16.X_RAPE_CASE,
      T19.X_REASON_OF_URGENCY,
      T19.X_REVIEW_FLG,
      T16.X_SENIOR_CITIZEN_FLAG,
      T19.X_SPECIAL_TAG,
      T16.X_STAY,
      T19.X_SUB_CATEGORY,
      T19.X_SUBJECT_OF_CASE,
      T19.X_YEAR,
      T16.TIME_ELAPSED,
      T19.X_TODAY_FLG,
      T16.ATTRIB_03,
      T19.X_WINDING_UP_CLOSURE,
      T19.X_REF_NUMBER,
      T19.MSTR_CASE_ID,
      T19.NAME,
      T16.ATTRIB_25,
      T16.ATTRIB_06,
      T16.X_ORG_UNIT,
      T16.ATTRIB_07,
      T6.OWNER_PER_ID,
      T16.ATTRIB_41,
      T19.PAR_CASE_ID,
      T16.ATTRIB_46,
      T16.ATTRIB_37,
      T19.X_CLOB_01,
      T19.PR_AGENCY_ID,
      T19.PR_REP_DNRM_FLG,
      T19.PR_REP_MANL_FLG,
      T19.PR_REP_SYS_FLG,
      T19.PR_SGROUP_ID,
      T19.BU_ID,
      T19.PR_PRTNR_ID,
      T19.PR_POSTN_ID,
      T19.PR_PROD_INT_ID,
      T19.PR_SUSPCT_ID,
      T16.ATTRIB_39,
      T19.ASGN_DT,
      T16.X_ATTRIB_DSC_03,
      T16.X_RECVD_FROM_ID,
      T19.REWARD_AMT,
      T19.REWARD_CURCY_CD,
      T19.REWARD_EXCH_DATE,
      T19.X_SRL_NUMBER,
      T19.X_SERIAL_

ObjMgrLog   Error   1   000000025a2722fc:0  2017-12-06 03:31:01 (oracon.cpp (3899)) SBL-DBC-00105: An error has occurred executing a Sql statement.

Please continue or ask your systems administrator to check your application configuration if the problem persists.

SQLParseAndExecute  Execute 5   000000025a2722fc:0  2017-12-06 03:31:01 ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

In the spool, the logs are:

```
SELECT
      T19.CONFLICT_ID,
      T19.LAST_UPD,
      T19.CREATED,
      T19.LAST_UPD_BY,
      T19.CREATED_BY,
      T19.MODIFICATION_NUM,
      T19.ROW_ID,
      T19.ROW_ID,
      T19.LAST_UPD,
      T19.,
      T19.APPEALED_FLG,
      T19.PS_APPL_ID,
      T19.APPR_TEMP_ID,
      T19.EVAL_ASSESS_ID,
      T19.ASGN_USR_EXCLD_FLG,
      T19.AUDIT_EMP_ID,
      T19.X_AUDIT_SERIAL_NUM,
      T16.X_CPC,
      T19.CASE_NUM,
      T16.ATTRIB_44,
      T19.SERIAL_NUM,
      T16.ATTRIB_01,
      T19.CATEGORY_TYPE_CD,
      T19.CITY,
      T19.CLASS_CD,
      T19.CLOSED_DT,
      T16.ATTRIB_42,
      T16.ATTRIB_47,
      T16.ATTRIB_45,
      T19.COUNTRY,
      T16.ATTRIB_44,
      T19.CASE_DT,
      T16.ATTRIB_07,
      T19.DESC_TEXT,
      T19.X_REFER_TO_PROSECUTION_FLG,
      T19.X_ASSIGN_AUTO_MANUAL,
      T16.ATTRIB_04,
      T19.X_REHAB_COURT_PROCEEDING_FLAG,
      T16.ATTRIB_09,
      T19.X_APPLICANT_ID,
      T19.X_CASE_CHARGES,
      T19.X_COURT_SESSION_DT,
      T19.X_COURT_SESSION_DT,
      T7.OCCUR_DT,
      T19.X_CRNT_SESSN_ID,
      T19.X_DIVISION_NAME,
      T10.POSTN_ID,
      T19.X_JOINCASE_FLG,
      T19.X_JOINCASE_ID,
      T16.ATTRIB_26,
      T19.,
      T19.X_OLD_SERIAL_NUM,
      T19.X_ON_BEHALF_ID,
      T19.X_PANEL_ID,
      T13.NAME,
      T19.X_PANEL_SCHED_ID,
      T8.POSTN_ID,
      T19.X_OFFENSE_ID,
      T16.X_POLICE_DIVISION,
      T19.X_POLICE_OTHERS,
      T4.POSTN_TYPE_CD,
      T16.X_REHAB_ARCHIVE_REASON,
      T16.X_REHAB_DESCRIPTION,
      T16.X_DATE_1,
      T19.X_ROOT_ROW_ID,
      T19.X_SR_ID,
      T16.X_REHAB_NOTES,
      T15.OCCUR_DT,
      T19.X_CLOB_02,
      T19.ORG_GROUP_ID,
      T19.CHANGED_FLG,
      T19.X_CASE_NAME,
      T16.X_COURTHOUSE,
      T16.X_DISPOSITION,
      T16.X_DISTRICT_NUM,
      T16.X_INTERPRETER,
      T16.X_JUDGE,
      T16.X_JURISDICTION,
      T16.X_PROSECUTOR,
      T16.X_STATUES,
      T19.X_FILING_APPEAL_DATE,
      T19.TYPE_CD,
      T19.X_BUNDLE_ID,
      T19.X_CM_TYPE,
      T19.X_CASE_DATE,
      T19.X_PARTY_TYPE,
      T16.CATEGORY_CODE,
      T19.X_COMPLEXITY,
      T19.X_CONVICTED,
      T19.X_CONVICTED_ID,
      T19.X_COPY_APPLY_DATE,
      T19.X_COPY_ISSUANCE_DATE,
      T19.X_COPY_JUDGMENT_DT,
      T19.X_COURT_FEE_VALUE,
      T19.X_DAYS_APPLICABLE,
      T16.ATTRIB_24,
      T19.LOCAL_SEQ_NUM,
      T19.X_DIARY_DATE,
      T19.X_DIARY_NUM,
      T16.X_DISABLED_FLAG,
      T19.X_DISTRICT,
      T19.X_JUDGE_ID,
      T19.X_FIR_NUM,
      T19.X_FIR_REGISTRATION_DT,
      T16.X_FAST_TRACK,
      T19.X_FEE_APPLICABLE,
      T19.X_FEE_TO_PAY,
      T16.X_FEMALE_FLAG,
      T16.X_GOVT_OFFICIAL,
      T19.X_IS_APPEAL,
      T19.X_IS_REVISION,
      T19.X_JUDGE_DESIGNATION,
      T19.X_JUDGE_NAME_URDU,
      T19.X_JUDGEMENT_DT,
      T16.X_JUVENILE_FLAG,
      T19.X_LEGAL_TIME_ELASPED,
      T19.X_COUNTY,
      T19.X_OTHER_CATEGORY,
      T16.X_OVERSEAS,
      T14.SERIAL_NUM,
      T14.X_SRL_NUMBER,
      T14.X_CASE_NAME,
      T14.X_SRL_NUMBER,
      T14.STATUS_CD,
      T19.X_QUEUE_NUMBER,
      T16.X_RAPE_CASE,
      T19.X_REASON_OF_URGENCY,
      T19.X_REVIEW_FLG,
      T16.X_SENIOR_CITIZEN_FLAG,
      T19.X_SPECIAL_TAG,
      T16.X_STAY,
      T19.X_SUB_CATEGORY,
      T19.X_SUBJECT_OF_CASE,
      T19.X_YEAR,
      T16.TIME_ELAPSED,
      T19.X_TODAY_FLG,
      T16.ATTRIB_03,
      T19.X_WINDING_UP_CLOSURE,
      T19.X_REF_NUMBER,
      T19.MSTR_CASE_ID,
      T19.NAME,
      T16.ATTRIB_25,
      T16.ATTRIB_06,
      T16.X_ORG_UNIT,
      T16.ATTRIB_07,
      T6.OWNER_PER_ID,
      T16.ATTRIB_41,
      T19.PAR_CASE_ID,
      T16.ATTRIB_46,
      T16.ATTRIB_37,
      T19.X_CLOB_01,
      T19.PR_AGENCY_ID,
      T19.PR_REP_DNRM_FLG,
      T19.PR_REP_MANL_FLG,
      T19.PR_REP_SYS_FLG,
      T19.PR_SGROUP_ID,
      T19.BU_ID,
      T19.PR_PRTNR_ID,
      T19.PR_POSTN_ID,
      T19.PR_PROD_INT_ID,
      T19.PR_SUSPCT_ID,
      T16.ATTRIB_39,
      T19.ASGN_DT,
      T16.X_ATTRIB_DSC_03,
      T16.X_RECVD_FROM_ID,
      T19.REWARD_AMT,
      T19.REWARD_CURCY_CD,
      T19.REWARD_EXCH_DATE,
      T19.X_SRL_NUMBER,
      T19.X_SERIAL_ISSUANCE_DATE,
      T19.STATE,
      T19.STATUS_CD,
      T19.STATUS_CD,
      T19.SUB_STATUS_CD,
      T16.ATTRIB_43,
      T19.PR_SUBJECT_ID,
      T19.SUBJECT_NAME,
      T19.SUBJECT_PH_NUM,
      T17.FST_NAME,
      T17.LAST_NAME,
      T19.TERRITORY_TYPE_CD,
      T19.CRIME_TYPE_CD,
      T19.THREAT_LVL_CD,
      T19.CRIME_SUB_TYPE_CD,
      T19.TYPE_CD,
      T19.X_URGENT_CASE_FLG,
      T19.X_VALUE_JURISDICTION,
      T19.BU_ID,
      T19.X_CASE_MODE,
      T16.X_REHAB_TYPE,
      T19.X_RELATIONSHIP,
      T13.X_PANEL_TYPE,
      T19.X_COURT_STAGE,
      T19.PRIORITY_TYPE_CD,
      T16.ATTRIB_05,
      T16.ATTRIB_38,
      T19.X_RECEIVING_METHOD,
      T19.X_REHAB_STATUS,
      T19.SOURCE_CD,
      T19.STAGE_CD,
      T19.SUB_TYPE_CD,
      T5.ROW_ID,
      T11.LOGIN,
      T3.FST_NAME,
      T3.SPOUSE_LAST_NAME,
      T2.FST_NAME,
      T2.SPOUSE_LAST_NAME,
      T16.ROW_ID,
      T16.PAR_ROW_ID,
      T16.MODIFICATION_NUM,
      T16.CREATED_BY,
      T16.LAST_UPD_BY,
      T16.CREATED,
      T16.LAST_UPD,
      T16.CONFLICT_ID,
      T16.PAR_ROW_ID,
      T12.ROW_ID,
      T5.ROW_ID,
      T18.ROW_ID,
      T9.ROW_ID
   FROM 
       SIEBEL.S_POSTN T1,
       SIEBEL.S_CONTACT T2,
       SIEBEL.S_CONTACT T3,
       SIEBEL.S_POSTN T4,
       SIEBEL.S_PARTY T5,
       SIEBEL.S_CONTACT T6,
       SIEBEL.S_INCIDENT T7,
       SIEBEL.S_CASE_POSTN T8,
       SIEBEL.S_PARTY T9,
       SIEBEL.S_CASE_POSTN T10,
       SIEBEL.S_USER T11,
       SIEBEL.S_CASE_POSTN T12,
       SIEBEL.S_PROJ T13,
       SIEBEL.S_CASE T14,
       SIEBEL.S_INCIDENT T15,
       SIEBEL.S_CASE_X T16,
       SIEBEL.S_CONTACT T17,
       SIEBEL.S_PARTY T18,
       SIEBEL.S_CASE T19
   WHERE 
      T19.AUDIT_EMP_ID = T6.PAR_ROW_ID (+) AND
      T19.X_CRNT_SESSN_ID = T7.ROW_ID (+) AND
      T19.X_PANEL_ID = T13.ROW_ID (+) AND
      T19.ROW_ID = T10.CASE_ID (+) AND T10.X_PANEL_ROLE (+) = 'Head of Bench' AND
      T19.ROW_ID = T8.CASE_ID (+) AND T8.X_PANEL_ROLE (+) = 'Panel Secretary' AND
      T19.PAR_CASE_ID = T14.ROW_ID (+) AND T19.PAR_CASE_ID = T14.ROW_ID (+) AND
      T19.PR_POSTN_ID = T4.PAR_ROW_ID (+) AND
      T19.ROW_ID = T15.X_CASE_ID (+) AND T15.X_STATUS_CD (+) = 'Scheduled' AND
      T19.PR_SUBJECT_ID = T17.ROW_ID (+) AND
      T19.ROW_ID = T16.PAR_ROW_ID (+) AND
      T19.PR_POSTN_ID = T12.POSTN_ID AND T19.ROW_ID = T12.CASE_ID AND
      T12.POSTN_ID = T5.ROW_ID AND
      T12.POSTN_ID = T1.PAR_ROW_ID (+) AND
      T1.PR_EMP_ID = T11.PAR_ROW_ID (+) AND
      T19.X_ON_BEHALF_ID = T18.ROW_ID (+) AND
      T19.X_ON_BEHALF_ID = T3.PAR_ROW_ID (+) AND
      T19.X_APPLICANT_ID = T9.ROW_ID (+) AND
      T19.X_APPLICANT_ID = T2.PAR_ROW_ID (+) AND
      (T19.X_PARTY_TYPE = 'CM') AND
      (T19.PAR_CASE_ID = '1-348TLP')
```

Now from above logs, the problem is T19., is being selected without a column name. I checked and all fields have proper columns. I am not sure how to debug it further.

Comment: Have you tried the "validate" option in Siebel tools? Maybe they will help identify the problem with the BC (along with another 800 warnings and errors that can be safely ignored... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and here is how i did it.

I cloned the same BC disabled all disabled following one by one and kept testing:

- Escripts
- User properties
- Multi-valued fields
- Removed the duplicate fields mapping on the same column
- Removed the fields with no column / calculated value at all
- Inactivated all other fields which

After doing that i was able to use CopyRecord method.